# Updating the emberJS view after an ajax request

Tags: ajax, ember.js

So I am trying to send a custom action to my server with ajax and update the emberJS model in the callback. My controller code looks like this:

```
PlatformUI.CampaignItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    deleteCampaign: function(){
      var campaign = this.get('model');
      campaign.deleteRecord();
      campaign.save();
    },
    startCampaign: function(){
      var campaign = this.get('model');
      $.ajax({
        url: '/campaigns/' + campaign.get('id') + '/campaign_start.json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
          campaign.set('status', data.started);
          //campaign.save();
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(xhr);
          alert('start campaign failed');
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

My model looks like this:

```
PlatformUI.Campaign = DS.Model.extend({

  name: DS.attr('string'),
  status: DS.attr('string'),
  updated_at: DS.attr('date'),
  user_id: DS.attr('number'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  started: function(){
    return this.get('status') == 'true';
  }.property()
});
```

Edit: adding template:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1> Campaigns
    List
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="/campaigns/new">Create New</a>
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Last updated</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     {{#each campaign in model itemController="CampaignItem"}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{campaign.id}}</td>
          <td>{{campaign.name}}</td>
          <td>{{ternary campaign.status "Started" "Stopped"}}</td>
          <td>{{campaign.updated_at}}</td>
          <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" {{bind-attr href=campaign.edit_url}}>Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" {{action "deleteCampaign"}}>Delete</a>
            {{#if campaign.started}}
              <a class="btn btn-primary" {{bind-attr href=campaign.stop_url}}>Stop</a>
            {{else}}
              <a class="btn btn-primary" {{action "startCampaign"}}>Start</a>
            {{/if}}
          </td>
        </tr>
     {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that it is not refreshing the view when I perform that action. I am new to emberJS so I don't really know if the model was really updated either.

Comment: Can you post your view? Also, you can use the [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) to check the state of your models.

Comment: @Oren the inspector tells me the model was updated.

Comment: I added the template and some missing lines in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let `started` know that it is calculated off of `status` so it knows to recaclulate when `status` is changed.

You can do this by including the `status` in the list of dependencies.

```
started: function(){
    return this.get('status') == 'true';
  }.property('status')
```

Comment: You should also change the equality comparison to `===`

Comment: I just noticed I could set the attribute type to boolean which simplify things quite a lot.

Comment: Yes, that definitely will help you. Wasn't sure what if status in your case implied a boolean.